# Data frame column multiplication with NA value

Tags: r

I want to generate a new column C which is the multiplication of A and B in my dataframe, however A and B may contain random NA value. If any of A or B is NA, then C should be NA too.

What I did was

```
data$C <- data$A * data$B
```

and the expected result would be

```
    A   B    C
[1] 2   3    6
[2] 4   NA   NA
[3] NA  2    NA
[4] 3.2 1.5  4.8
```

However, the actual result gives me NA for all of C, that is

```
    A   B    C
[1] 2   3    NA
[2] 4   NA   NA
[3] NA  2    NA
[4] 3.2 1.5  NA
```

How can I fix this? Im using Rstudio btw. Thank you in advance

Comment: `data$A * data$B` works fine for me.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a complete reproducible example, including the code to generate your data frame.

Comment: Given their printing, those look like matrices, not data frames...

Comment: @alistaire Yes, but then `data$A` wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: @ClausWilke Yeah, my point was more that we'd need to see `dput(data)` to have any idea what's going on here

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're doing. This definitely works:

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(2, 4, NA, 3.2),
                   B = c(3, NA, 2, 1.5))
data
#     A   B
# 1 2.0 3.0
# 2 4.0  NA
# 3  NA 2.0
# 4 3.2 1.5

data$C <- data$A * data$B
data
#     A   B   C
# 1 2.0 3.0 6.0
# 2 4.0  NA  NA
# 3  NA 2.0  NA
# 4 3.2 1.5 4.8
```

Comment: May be the 'C' column is `character` in the OP's dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ifelse` statement:

```
data$C <- ifelse(is.na(data$A) || is.na.(data$B), NA, data$A * data$B)
```

Comment: That works but shouldn't be necessary.